# Ubuntu not showing in MSCONFIG boot tab

Tags: boot, grub-efi, windows-11

I installed ubuntu after windows 11 but, it showed grub, but i wanted to use the windows bootloader instad, but when i open MSCONFIG and boot tab, ubuntu was not shown. Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wzsa.png)

Comment: booting Ubuntu from windows bootloader is not supported IIRC